# Get description of a venue from Foursquare with React

Tags: reactjs, foursquare

I'm trying to return a venue's description using React.JS and the Foursquare API.

I understand that you need to pass the venue's ID to retrieve any additional venue information and currently I'm able to pull a certain amount of venues but none of the descriptions are appearing. Attached below is my current app.js file (with authentication details X'd out) and a screenshot of what I'm seeing in my browser.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './App.css';


var foursquare = require('react-foursquare')({
  clientID: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  clientSecret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'  
});

var params = {
  "near": "Wilkes-Barre, PA",
  "categoryId": '4d4b7105d754a06374d81259',
  "radius":"250"
};

export default class FoursquareDemo extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       items: [],
       place: null

     };
   }

  componentDidMount() {    
    foursquare.venues.getVenues(params)
      .then(res=> {
        this.setState({ items: res.response.venues });
      });

  }


  render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <div>Items:</div>
        { this.state.items.map(item=> { return <div key={item.id}>{item.name} - {item.location.city} - {foursquare.venues.getVenue(item.id).description}</div>}) }
        <br />

    </div>
  )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <FoursquareDemo />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Browser Screenshot:

[image: browser screenshot]

Ideally, I'd like to pull the description in after the venue name and the hyphen "-".

Comment: You're treating getVenue() as if it's synchronous.  You need to loop through the results from getVenues() in componentDidMount() and add the description there.

Comment: @rooch84 Sorry, I'm a little new to React still - should I be doing this in the componentDidMount function as it's pulling each item and placing it into the state? Am I able manipulate the items array elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, in componentDidMount once you get the venues.